# Highlighting HTML text input fields without losing native look and feel in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, textinput

In Chrome, I can set the `background-color` of a text input field and all that changes is the background color.  In this way I can highlight fields that need to be paid attention to (make the background light red so that the user knows there's a mistake there).  In Firefox, and I suspect other browsers, the background color is changed, but the text field also looks more plain.  Inset shadows disappear and when focused on the field there's no blue glow around it.  It just looks different.

Is there a way to highlight a text field without changing the look and feel of it in Firefox (and other similar browsers)?

***UPDATE***: Example code:

```
<ul>
<li><input type="text" style="background-color: red"/></li>
<li><input type="text"/></li>
</ul>
```

You can see the difference between the 2 text fields. Hovering and focusing on the normal text field feels native to the OS. But the text field with a red background isn't as good anymore.

[Here's the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/uUp3g/).

Comment: can you please show the code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue back then, seems that if you want to change the background-color, you must change the border style for Firefox, 2px solid and the color of your choice.

Comment: Well it's more than just the border style. Hovering, focusing and shadows all play a role. I'm sure I could emulate all this with Javascript/jQuery and testing which OS and browser the user's on... but obviously I don't want to.

Comment: You couldn't emulate it even if you wanted to, because the user can change all those settings on the OS level.  Which is the same problem Firefox has: it can ask the OS "how do I draw a text input that looks like it's native?" but not "how do I draw a text input that looks like it's native but has this totally different background color?".

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not believe so.  Opera has the same behavior as Firefox.  The best solution I came up with was to only style the elements *if* they required the user's attention (the element has focus or contains invalid data).

This is what I use as part of my Sass bootstrap:

```
@mixin background($image, $bgcolor) { background: $bgcolor url(#{$imagedir}#{$image}) no-repeat scroll right center }

input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]), textarea, select {
    font: inherit;
    // background-color background-image background-repeat background-attachment background-position

    &:required:valid, &:required:in-range {
        //border: 1px solid #0f0;

        &:focus { outline: 1px solid #0f0; @include background("tick.png", transparent); }
    }

    &:invalid, &:out-of-range {
        @include background("asterisk_orange.png", $required-bg);
        border: 1px solid $required-color;

        &:focus {
            background-image: url("#{$imagedir}exclamation.png"); outline: 1px solid $required-color;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the generated CSS looks like:

```
input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]), textarea, select {
  font: inherit;
}
input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):required:valid:focus, input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):required:in-range:focus, textarea:required:valid:focus, textarea:required:in-range:focus, select:required:valid:focus, select:required:in-range:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #0f0;
  background: transparent url(icons/silk/tick.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
}
input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):invalid, input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):out-of-range, textarea:invalid, textarea:out-of-range, select:invalid, select:out-of-range {
  background: #fef8b4 url(icons/silk/asterisk_orange.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):invalid:focus, input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):out-of-range:focus, textarea:invalid:focus, textarea:out-of-range:focus, select:invalid:focus, select:out-of-range:focus {
  background-image: url("icons/silk/exclamation.png");
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
input:not([type^="date"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]):focus + .tip, textarea:focus + .tip, select:focus + .tip {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fef8b4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px .5em;
}
```

It's worth noting that for Opera, outline does not cause the element to lose its default styling like border/background does.